# Clustering nodes based on structure of local neighbourhood in a graph

Tags: clustering

I would like to cluster nodes in a graph based on the structure of their local neighbourhood, i.e. nodes with similar graph structure around each other should be in the same cluster. My issue is basically to define a good feature set with a metric that would result in reasonable clusters. Does anyone know of any such features? :)

Comment: Can you give more details about your dataset (graphs and nodes)? What are the attributes contained in nodes for example?

Comment: Right know I am mainly concerned about the structure of the graph itself, not the particularities of the nodes, i.e. the features should reflect the local graph structure. E.g. how many neighbours

Comment: For terms like 'reasonable clusters' to be meaningful, we need to know what data the graph is constructed from, what theoretical model is assumed or what function is being optimized.

Comment: To put this in another way: are there any good features, measures if you would like, that characterises the local structures of a graph? Are there any distance function that takes as input two local graph structures and spits out a meaningful measure of how similar they are?

Comment: Representation of data. I am dealing with local neighbourhoods, small graphs, rather than images e.g. For an image one could for example use histogram of oriendted gradients, but what would I use for graphs?

Comment: I think this could be developed into an interesting question, I don't agree it should be put on hold. What it really needs is just a bit more expanding and explaining what are "local graph structures" and what graphs are of interest..